# How do you get the log information section via Project.Logs object in test complete

Tags: testcomplete

In the test complete application there is a section called information for an open script test log:

[image]

Using the automation object Project.Logs how can I access this data?

I have looked throughout the smartbear help:

https://support.smartbear.com/testcomplete/docs/testing-with/log/working-with/from-tests.html

With this link providing the best example for accessing logs in general - however there doesnt seem to be any mention of how to access the test logs timestamp information.

Google doesn't seem to have any answers either...

I can get the timestamp for a particular row of the test - however I only want to process the log if its timestamp is today.

Any suggestions on how I might achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

if you are trying to read the timestamp of the log file 
you can export the log flie using:

```
Log.SaveResultsAs("C:\\Work\\Log.mht", lsMHT);
```

and also you can get the timestamp(creation time) of the same file using the below code snippet:

```
function get()
{
  var myObject, f, date;
    myObject = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
    f = myObject.GetFile("c:\\mytest.txt");
    date = f.DateCreated;
    Log.Message("The date this file was created is: " + date);
}
```

Regards,
Sathish Kumar K